# In R, sample enough rows in a dataframe that no column is empty

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr, na

I have a large dataframe `df` in R with many columns, many NAs, but no column is entirely NA.  I am interested in a specific list `col_list` of those columns.  I want a sample of the dataframe so that each column is represented at least once.

My thought was to "iterate" via `map_dfr` over the list of columns, filtering `df` to where each column is not NA, and then sampling one row from there, as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)

col_list %>% 
  map_dfr(function(name){
    df %>% 
      filter(!is.na(name)) %>% 
      sample_n(1)
  }) %>% 
  select(all_of(col_list))
```

Unfortunately, some columns are still turning up empty in the result.  From the looks of it, the few columns that keep coming up empty have above average amounts of NAs for the dataframe, but I know they're not entirely empty.

I cannot share my dataset, and I cannot think of how to reproduce this on a smaller one, so unfortunately I am unable to produce a reprex.

What could the gap in my logic above be, and how might it be improved to get no columns all NA?

Edit: I've accepted the first solution below. I've also solved it with better [env-variable selection](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), so I'm posting here for posterity.

```
library(tidyverse)

col_list %>% 
  map_dfr(function(name){
    df %>% 
      filter(!is.na(.data[[name]])) %>%
      sample_n(1)
  }) %>% 
  select(all_of(col_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example (based on my best understanding of your question):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = c('hello', 'yes', 'no', NA), 
  y = c(NA, NA, NA, 'hi'), 
  z = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)

col_list <- names(df)

col_list %>% 
  map_dfr(function(name){
    df %>% 
      filter(!is.na(name)) %>% 
      sample_n(1)
  }) %>% 
  select(all_of(col_list))
```

In this scenario, the `filter()` function is looking for the column named `name` which (probably) does not exist. You could wrap `name` in `!!sym()` and that should do the trick.

```
col_list %>% 
  map_dfr(function(name){
    df %>% 
      filter(!is.na(!!sym(name))) %>% 
      sample_n(1)
  }) %>% 
  select(all_of(col_list))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I also found that replacing `name` with `.data[[name]]` fixes it from a tidy evaluation standpoint.  I'll have to learn more about this.